Why calves are stretched during the good morning exercise
While exercising the good morning exercise (forward hip bend), I feel a strong stretch in my calves.
How is that, despite the knees and the femur don't change position in that exercise?
Where does that stretch come from?

The stretch in your calves during the good morning exercise comes from the tension placed on the calf muscles, particularly the gastrocnemius, as they work to stabilize the ankle joint.
In the good morning exercise, you’re hinging at the hips with a mostly straight leg, which lengthens the hamstrings and also affects the posterior chain of muscles, including the calves. The gastrocnemius muscle crosses both the knee and the ankle joints, so even though the knee doesn’t change position significantly, any movement that stretches the posterior chain (like hip flexion) can increase tension through this entire pathway.
When you lean forward, the angle of your ankle joint changes slightly, especially if you shift your weight back onto your heels for balance, which increases the dorsiflexion (upward flex) angle at the ankle. This subtle change can further stretch the calf muscles, which is likely what you’re feeling during the movement.
